# How to send object that contains array via AJAX POST in Django

Tags: arrays, ajax, django, post

I am trying to send a object with an array inside of it via an AJAX POST in Django when the user clicks a button. I am following the instructions on the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/) have hit a snag. I am attempting to see a specific indice in the array using `logger.debug()` in the view and am not able to access the contents. How do I access that specific element in the array?

***My AJAX...***

```
var tags_selected = [1,2,3,4]

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});

$("#filter").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/pensieve/filtertags",
    data: {'tags': tags_selected},
    success: function(res){
      console.log(res)
    },
    dataType: "json"
  });
})
```

***My View...***

```
def filter_tags(request):
    logger.debug(request.POST)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'response': 111}), content_type="application/json")
```

***My DEBUG log in my terminal...***

```
DEBUG - 2016-05-06:17:15:50 - <QueryDict: {u'tags[]': [u'142', u'122', u'138']}>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get values of the `tags[]` Array with `getlist()` method.

Example :

```python
request.POST.getlist('tags[]')
# outputs : ['1', '2', '3']
request.POST.getlist('tags[]')[1]
# outputs : '2'
```

Comment: Thanks! This totally helped me!